# c# run an async task in background when parent returns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am writing a MVC5 app that has a controller with a function say `Method1`

I have a third party function that is `async Task`, let's call it `DoMethodAsync` (it essentially makes a POST call).

I want to call it right before returning from `Method1` but I don't really care about the result of the async task, if it fails, it fails. How can I fire and forget and have it execute in the background so that it does not block the controller from responding to other requests?

How can I ensure that `DoMethodAsync` is only executed after `Method1` has returned?

Comment: So are you wanting to call the async function before or after Method1 returns? It's an asnyc function... so no matter where you call it, it's not going to block the controller as long as you don't `await` it.

Comment: Just don't await the `DoMethodAsync`, this will generate a compiler warning but you can ignore it as it's doing what you want.

Comment: @codinggorilla oh wow really? i can do that?
@JonathanCarroll I want `DoMethodAsync` to run after i return. but since `Method1` is the only function the controller has access to, i gotta create the `DoMethodAsync` inside of it, right before returning

Answer (score 15):

> I don't really care about the result of the async task, if it fails, it fails.

Really? Just asking, because this is an extremely rare use case.

> How can I fire and forget and have it execute in the background so that it does not block the controller from responding to other requests?

I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) that looks into various approaches to "fire and forget" tasks on ASP.NET.

You *don't* want to just call the method and ignore the returned task, because that method will inherit the request context for the initiating request. Then after the request is completed, the request context is disposed, and that method can end up in an "interesting" place - some things will work, but others will not.

So, the minimum viable solution is to wrap it in `Task.Run`:

```
var _ignored = Task.Run(() => DoMethodAsync());
```

However, note that ASP.NET is completely unaware of this "extra operation". If you want `DoMethodAsync` to have more of a chance of actually executing to completion, then you'll want to register it with the ASP.NET runtime, either using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` (4.5.2+) or [my own `BackgroundTaskManager.Run`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) (4.5.0/4.5.1).

Also note that *none* of these options will guarantee that `DoMethodAsync` will run to completion; they just give you a "best effort." For a truly reliable system, you'd need a proper distributed architecture, i.e., reliable storage with an independent processor.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer. To the first point, I do care but i'd rather get this working first. If it changes the implementation then I definitely will go with the one that allows me to catch the failure. With `Run` it would not block the caller? What do you mean by "no guarantee to run to completion" ? will they just stop halfway or will they not execute it? I did consider Hangfire, but prefer something lighter first

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha: I mean that ASP.NET is designed around responding to requests. It is not designed to be used to do work *outside* of a request. When there are no requests, IIS can shut it down (and *will* recycle it occasionally in an attempt to keep things clean). If you have a `Task.Run` task going at that time, it'll be unceremoniously killed.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary I went to may tutorials .. only this answer helper .. now my code is running without affecting user working experience. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not "an extremely rare use case" that you want to kick off background work based on a request, but you don't want the request to wait until that work is done. You think a forgot-password mechanism is an extremely rare use case? You think it's extremely rare to log user activity but not want to bog down their request waiting for the logging operation to complete?

Comment: @CarlLeth: I stated it's extremely rare to *not care whether the operation fails* (or indeed, whether it completes at all). It would be extremely rare for the forgot-password mechanism to ignore all email-sending errors. The common solution for forgot-password is a proper distributed architecture (queue + service); and the common solution for logging is an in-memory queue that is flushed on shutdown. Async fire-and-forget *should be* extremely rare.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but after hours of searching and trying different things myself, I came across this thread. Combining some info here with other resource, I was able to implement what I wanted which I believe is the same thing the OP wanted.

I wanted to call a URL like /API/Start and I wanted that URL to instantly return a view that said "Thank you for starting, check back later". However it needed to then simply kick off a background job.

This is with MVC 5 so not sure if it makes a difference, but...

Side Note: To see this in action, use 2 URL's
/Default/Index    <-- will report back ~5 seconds
/Default/IndexAsync  <--  will report back ~0 seconds (well sort of .. you'll see)

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{

    // GET: Sync
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myStopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        myStopwatch.Start();
        DoTask();
        myStopwatch.Stop();

        ViewBag.Message = ($"Process took {myStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()}");
        return View("Index");
    }

    // GET: Async
    public ActionResult IndexAsync()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myStopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        myStopwatch.Start();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(DoTaskAsync);
        myStopwatch.Stop();

        ViewBag.Message = ($"Process took {myStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()}");
        return View("Index");
    }

    // "the Sync Task"
    private void DoTask()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"DoTask Started at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"DoTask Finished at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    }

    // "the Async Task"
    private async Task DoTaskAsync()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"DoTaskAsync Started at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"DoTaskAsync Finished at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    }      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling an asynchronous method means that the calling method (your code) will **not** be blocked while the async method is executing, at least not by default (you can make your code block via the 'await' keyword or via calling one of the task's blocking methods like 'Result' or 'Wait', etc...).
That means that if you just call that method, the method will run asynchronously and your code will not wait for it to end. I think that exactly what you want.

Comment: cool! but what if i want to guarantee `DoMethodAsync` to execute after `Method1` has returned? but i dont have access to things outside of `Method1`. Is there a better way then setting a time on `DoMethodAsync` ?

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha what exactly is the purpose of the thing you want to do?

Comment: What difference does it make as long as its non blocking async task

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DoMethodAsync(); // if you do not await and simple call this task it will run in backround as you want
    return View();
}

async Task DoMethodAsync()
{
    // calculate something
}
```